# Why is Rashid Nezhmetdinov not as popular/known as Mikhail Tal?

Tags: famous-players

I was looking at some games between of `Rashid Nezhmetdinov` and noticed he doesn't seem to be as popular (I don't know if this is the best word) or as well-known as `Mikhail Tal`.  After reading some of the things said about him, you would think this is not the case:

> "Nobody sees combinations like Rashid Nezhmetdinov." Mikhail Botvinnik
>
> Nezhmetdinov is "the greatest master of the initiative." Lev
>   Polugaevsky
>
> "His games reveal the beauty of chess and make you love in
>   chess not so much the points and high placings, but the wonderful
>   harmony and elegance of this particular world." Mikhail Tal
>
> "Rashid
>   Nezhmetdinov is a virtuoso of combinational chess." David Bronstein

Here is his most celebrated brilliancy vs `Lev Polugaevsky`, featuring a stunning queen sacrifice:

```
[FEN ""]
1.d4 Nf6 2.c4 d6 3.Nc3 e5 4.e4 exd4 5.Qxd4 Nc6 6.Qd2 g6 7.b3 Bg7 8.Bb2 O-O 9.Bd3 Ng4 10.Nge2 Qh4 11.Ng3 Nge5 12.O-O f5 13.f3 Bh6 14.Qd1 f4 15.Nge2 g5 16.Nd5 g4 17.g3 fxg3 18.hxg3 Qh3 19.f4 Be6 20.Bc2 Rf7 21.Kf2 Qh2+ 22.Ke3 Bxd5 23.cxd5 Nb4 24.Rh1 Rxf4!! 25.Rxh2 Rf3+ 26.Kd4 Bg7!! 27...b5! and 28...Nec6#. 27.a4 c5+ 28.dxc6 bxc6 29.Bd3 Nexd3+ 30.Kc4 d5+ 31.exd5 cxd5+ 32.Kb5 Rb8+ 33.Ka5 Nc6+ 0-1
```

Regarding the above game, Polugaevsky is quoted as saying, "I must have beaten Rashid a dozen times. But that one loss was so good I would have traded them all to be on the other side of the board."

Comment: Tal was a much stronger player; he was a World Champion.

Comment: Perhaps "much stronger" is unnecessarily strong. Especially since the personal score between Nezhmitdinov and Tal is 3-1 (all decisive games, where Nezhmitdinov was white in every game)http://www.chessgames.com/perl/chess.pl?yearcomp=exactly&year=&playercomp=either&pid=37199&player=&pid2=14380&player2=&movescomp=exactly&moves=&opening=&eco=&result=. This one http://www.chessgames.com/perl/chessgame?gid=1102235 is probably the most exciting.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Probably because he never made it to world champion, And Mikhail Tal did. Another great player that is not as popular as he deserves to be was [Akiba Rubinstein](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Akiba_Rubinstein)

Answer (score 1):

I will give a shot at answering this question as well.  I found a 3 part biography on `Rashid Nezhmitdinov` which you can find on youtube here ([part 1](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=T_Io7jbHsYs), [part 2](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3Fod6_K8ofY), [part 3](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Uo8hTNeJ3rw)).  According to the Biography, although `Rashid` beat many of the top grandmasters in his day and won the Russian championship many times, he never was able to achieve the `GM` title, but only the `IM` title.  Some theorize that he was not given a fair chance (not able play much internationally) because of his Tartar heritage and his faith, but this is only theory and `Rashid` would have never made any excuses.  It also seem like `Rashid` was always at the tip of being on the top, but could never place first in many tournaments.  He also seemed to a be inconsistent at times.